# Mongoose, Select a specific field with find

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to select only a specific field with

```
exports.someValue = function(req, res, next) {
    //query with mongoose
    var query = dbSchemas.SomeValue.find({}).select('name');

    query.exec(function (err, someValue) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(someValue);
    });
};
```

But in my json response i'm receiving also the _id, my document schema only has two fiels, _id and name

```
[{"_id":70672,"name":"SOME VALUE 1"},{"_id":71327,"name":"SOME VALUE 2"}]
```

Why???

Answer (score 301, accepted):

The `_id` field is always present unless you explicitly exclude it. Do so using the `-` syntax:

```
exports.someValue = function(req, res, next) {
    //query with mongoose
    var query = dbSchemas.SomeValue.find({}).select('name -_id');

    query.exec(function (err, someValue) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(someValue);
    });
};
```

Or explicitly via an object:

```
exports.someValue = function(req, res, next) {
    //query with mongoose
    var query = dbSchemas.SomeValue.find({}).select({ "name": 1, "_id": 0});

    query.exec(function (err, someValue) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.send(someValue);
    });
};
```

Comment: I think `.select` just is a filter to choose field after you get all of that, my recommendation is to use `.find({}, 'name -_id')`

Comment: @Hongarc `.find({}, 'name -_id')` seems not working?

Comment: is there is a way to get the value direct without an obj like
[ 'value1', 'value2', 'value3' ]
 instead of 
[ 'name':'value1',
'name':'value2',
'name':'value3' ]

Comment: I get an error using this because apparently I can't use a mixe of inclusions and rejections. I figured I should pass as argument to the `.select()` only this id to exclude it : `.select({ "_id":0 })`

Answer (score 83):

There is a shorter way of doing this now:

```
exports.someValue = function(req, res, next) {
    //query with mongoose
    dbSchemas.SomeValue.find({}, 'name', function(err, someValue){
      if(err) return next(err);
      res.send(someValue);
    });
    //this eliminates the .select() and .exec() methods
};
```

In case you want most of the `Schema fields` and want to omit only a few, you can prefix the field `name` with a `-` (minus sign).  For ex `"-name"` in the second argument will ***not*** include `name` field in the doc whereas the example given here will have ***only*** the `name` field in the returned docs.

Comment: For those who want to filter multiple fields, don't seperate them with comma, just plain space: `blogItemModel.find({}, 'title intro_image intro_text publish_date', function(err, blog_items){..`

Comment: for those who want to use where clause in above  **dbSchema.Somevalue.find({userEmail:'test@test.com'},'userEmail -_id', function(err, someValue)**

Comment: multiple fields would be ['name', 'field2', 'field3', 'etc'] instead of just 'name'

Answer (score 35):

There's a better way to handle it using Native MongoDB code in Mongoose.

```
exports.getUsers = function(req, res, next) {

    var usersProjection = { 
        __v: false,
        _id: false
    };

    User.find({}, usersProjection, function (err, users) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        res.json(users);
    });    
}
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/

Note:

> var usersProjection

The list of objects listed here will not be returned / printed.

Comment: How do you do this with findOne?

Comment: questionnaire needs on name json array. with your method other key are there than they also will come like age,etc

Comment: Awesome, just what i was looking for

Answer (score 34):

Tip: **0 means ignore & 1 means show.**

**Example 1:**

```
User.find({}, { createdAt: 0, updatedAt: 0, isActive: 0, _id : 1 }).then(...)
```

---

**Example 2:**

```
User.findById(id).select("_id, isActive").then(...)
```

---

**Example 3:**

```
User.findById(id).select({ _id: 1, isActive: 1, name: 1, createdAt: 0 }).then(...)
```

Comment: The most suitable solution for safety without any additional functions!

Comment: Seems you can no longer include mix of 0 and 1

Answer (score 21):

DB Data

```
[
  {
    "_id": "70001",
    "name": "peter"
  },
  {
    "_id": "70002",
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "_id": "70003",
    "name": "joseph"
  }
]
```

Query

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  "_id": 0,
  "name": 1
}).exec((Result)=>{
    console.log(Result);
})
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "name": "peter"
  },
  {
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "name": "joseph"
  }
]
```

Working sample playground

[link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Yu0xpdzPqkz)

Comment: this answer helped me, it explains in a easy to understanding way, +1 to you.

Answer (score 16):

#### Exclude

Below code will retrieve all fields other than password within each document:

```js
const users = await UserModel.find({}, {
  password: 0 
});
console.log(users);
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5dd3fb12b40da214026e0658",
    "email": "example@example.com"
  }
]
```

#### Include

Below code will only retrieve email field within each document:

```js
const users = await UserModel.find({}, {
  email: 1
});
console.log(users);
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "email": "example@example.com"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 6):

The precise way to do this is it to  use [**`.project()`**](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#project) cursor method with the new **`mongodb`** and **`nodejs`** driver.

```
var query = await dbSchemas.SomeValue.find({}).project({ name: 1, _id: 0 })
```

Comment: `.project()` works only with aggregate. If you want to use it with find use second argument in `find({},{ name: 1, _id: 0 })` method.

Comment: No with the new mongodb node driver you have to use this way. But with mongoose you can use second argument.

Comment: ah, it is in nodejs driver.

Comment: Don't understand why, but in new versions @Anthony is right...Lower versions you can do it this way...very messy

Answer (score 4):

I found a really good option in mongoose that uses **distinct** returns array all of a specific field in document.

`User.find({}).distinct('email').then((err, emails) => { // do something })`