# How can I select single column from MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a users table of the following schema

```
var usersSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  uname : {type : String , unique: true},
  email : {type : String},
  logintype : {type : String},
  password : String,
  status : String,
  hash : String,
  social: {},
  games: Object,
  os: String,
  friends: Object,
  msges:Object
});
```

I want to fetch `msges` of specific user. I have the username. Currently this is what I am doing

```
var getMessages = function(user){
    global.users.find({"uname" : uname},
        {"friends.friendUname":1,_id:0},
        function(err,doc){
            if(err){
                callback(false,err,"",null);
            }else{
                callback(true,null,"",doc);
            }
        }
        );
}
```

But I don't want all the fields. Any help?

Comment: Please search before ask,
Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find

Comment: I already searched before posting this question. I can't seem to get it right. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be something like this

```
global.users.find({"uname" : uname}, 'msges -_id', function (err, doc) {
    ...
})
```