# How can i send only particular field in json response using node and express.js?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express

```
[ 
{ 
   id: 6dcba0f57c9b73cc1,
   USER_ID: '945',
   ORDER_ID: '35220',
   PRODUCT_ID: '9982',
   CODE: '418567066',
   POINTS: '2000'

},
 {
   id: 4dcba0f57c9b73cc7,
   USER_ID: '945',
   ORDER_ID: '43521',
   PRODUCT_ID: '1071',
   CODE: '4004091261',
   POINTS: '1000',
 },
 { id: dcba0f57c9b73cce,
   USER_ID: '945',
   ORDER_ID: '13594',
   PRODUCT_ID: '2482',
   CODE: '7592231244',
   POINTS: '2000',
 },
 {
   id: 0f57c9b73cc74dcba,
   USER_ID: '345',
   ORDER_ID: '43528',
   PRODUCT_ID: '1071',
   CODE: '4004091267',
   POINTS: '1000',
 }
]
```

Above documents stored in my pointsummaries collection .

```
   id
   USER_ID
   ORDER_ID
   PRODUCT_ID
   CODE
   POINTS
```

instead of sending all the above fields in every document . i need to send only

```
USER_ID
 ORDER_ID 
 CODE
```

Below is my controller code which will display/send  only `USER_ID: '945'` point details.

```
exports.userpos = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    PointSummary.find({'USER_ID':'945'}).exec(function (err, PointSummarys) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
     //return res.status(200).json(PointSummarys);
     return res.status(200).json({});
  });
};
```

how can i solve this ?

Comment: Related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass all the fields that you want to be returned in the db query.

```
exports.userpos = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.params.id)
    PointSummary.find({'USER_ID':'945'}, {
        'USER_ID': 1,
        'ORDER_ID': 1,
        'CODE': 1
    }).exec(function (err, PointSummarys) {
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
     //return res.status(200).json(PointSummarys);
     return res.status(200).json({});
  });
};
```

Side note: Ideally, you would want to keep your key names in lower case. 
`user_id` instead of `USER_ID`

Comment: no what i  am asking response now i am sending all fields .but  i should send only USER_ID ,ORDER_ID ,CODE

Comment: The above code will only return `_id, USER_ID ,ORDER_ID ,CODE`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124705/based-on-value-how-to-create-new-document-using-node-js-mongodb