# How to query by one field and get specific field in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection as follows,
[image]

I want to get the cities for the specific country. what should be the query?

This is what i have tried.

```
db.getCollection('_event').find([
 {$match: {}},
 {$project: {
  cities: {
   $filter: {
    input: 'city',
    as: 'r',
    cond: {$eq: ['$$r.country', 'Portugal']}
   }
  }
 }}
])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose, Select a specific field with find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find)

Comment: Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing a screenshot of your data format, copy and paste or type the actual data into the post directly.
cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use as follow

```
db.getCollection('_event').find(
    {'location.country':'Portugal'},{'location.city':1}
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you have tried is the Pipeline way which is implement with **Aggregation** (For modification use aggregation)

```
db.getCollection('_event').aggregation([
 {$match: {}},
 {$project: {
  cities: {
   $filter: {
    input: 'city',
    as: 'r',
    cond: {$eq: ['$$r.country', 'Portugal']}
   }
  }
 }}
])
```

or in simple way (to get whole models):-

```
 1   db.getCollection('_event').find({"location.country":"Portugal"})
 2   db.getCollection('_event').find({"location.country":\Portugal\})
```

2nd is for same like Portugal

Thanks.