# Nodejs Mongoose get result array of property values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

How can I get an array of property values without the object structure. Here is my schema

```
  _id: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User"
},

services: [{
          _id:false,
          service_category: {

                      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                      ref: "ServiceCategory"
                },
          sub_services :[{
          _id:false,
          service : {
                      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                      ref: "Service"
                    }
          }]               
}]
```

And this is how I was going to query the results

```
 Vendor.find({ '_id': req.user._id, 'services.service_category':req.body.category_id},'services.sub_services.service').exec(function (err, rtnobj) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return (err);
    }
    else{
         res.send(rtnobj);
    }   
  })
```

But it gives me this output

```
[
    {
        "_id": "598b28271a0b551af8fbf849",
        "services": [
            {
                "sub_services": [
                    {
                        "service": "service 1 _id"
                    },
                    {
                        "service": "service 2 _id"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

But I need the result in following format

```
[ "service 1 _id", "service 2 _id",......]
```

Is there any standard approaches to do this. Or any alternative methods

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose, Select a specific field with find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find)

Comment: No, that is not similar with this question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a query, then you might as well just keep doing what you do now and then to map over the results:

```
 Vendor.find({ '_id': req.user._id, 'services.service_category':req.body.category_id},'services.sub_services.service').exec(function (err, rtnobj) {
     res.send(rtnobj.services.sub_services.map(each => each.service))
})
```

You could also use the aggregation framework to do something similar. but I think the above would be most idiomatic.

Comment: It works, But had to do some changes                                                                               res.send(rtnobj[0].services[0].sub_services.map(each => each.service));  Thanks for your support