# Express / MongoDb find all objects by ID and save them to an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My monongodb schema looks like this:

```
let statSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        title: String,
        statId: String,
        stats: {
            likeCount: Number,
            commentCount: Number
        }
    });

let MyStat = mongoose.model("MyStat", statSchema);
```

I am looking for a way where I can get all the `statId` elements from the database and put them in an array.

Later on I want to go through that array with `request` (npm request) that will take the `statId` and request JSON from API that will update all `stats`(likeCount and commentCount) for each corresponding `statId`.

If I use this code below:

```
MyStat.find({}, function(err, foundStats){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(foundStats);
  });
```

it will log all the elements in my database but I don't know how to access just 'statId'.

I was trying to use `console.log(foundStats.linkId);`but it returns `undefined`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongoose, Select a specific field with find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

foundStats is an array you need to loop in  them.

```
foundStats.forEach((element) => {
    console.log(element.statId);
});
```

if you want to return the statId only use it like this:

```
 MyStat.find({}, 'statId' , function(err, foundStats){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(foundStats);
  });
```

see the docs [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

Answer (score 0):

Your statId is stored as '_id'. So If you do not explicitly change or set id field, the object id field will be found in '_id'.

In this case, you might use

```
MyStat.find({}, '_id', function(err, foundStats){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(foundStats);
});
```

In the 'foundStats' you will find all the id of the stats.

For more check the [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find), [mongoDB](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#find_find)