# Get precise subdocuments in document array mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongoose

I'm developing a graphql API using mongoose to interact with my mongo database and I'm struggling with something. I have documents with subdocuments arrays and I need to get all the documents containing a subdocument that have a specific field value. The problem is I want to get only this subdocument in the document. It's easier to explain with an example :

My documents are like that :

```
documents: [
{
  id: 1,
  items: [
    {
      value: 5,
    },
    {
      value: 10,
    },
  ]
},
{
  id: 2,
  items: [
    {
      value: 7,
    },
    {
      value: 10,
    },
  ]
}]
```

I want to get all the documents that have an item with `value == 5`, but containing only this value like :

```
results : [
{
  id: 1,
  items: [
    {
      value: 5,
    }
  ]
}]
```

What I do for now is :

```
documents.find({
  items: {
    $elemMatch : {
      value: { $eq: 5 }
    }
  },
});
```

The thing is doing this I get the correct document, but it contains all the items, not only the ones that match the condition. I looked for a solution but I didn't find anything to do so.

Thanks for your help, I hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use the aggregation framework as follows:

```
db.test.aggregate(
{ $match: { "id": 1 }}, 
{ $unwind: '$items' }, 
{ $match: { "items.value": 5 }},
{ $project: { "_id": 0 }}
)
```

Return value:

```
{ "id" : 1, "items" : { "value" : 5 } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the fields you want to return from the query.

```
documents.find({
    items: {
      $elemMatch : {
        value: { $eq: 5 }
      }
    },
  }, {requiredFields: 1});
```

See example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find) question.

Official docs: [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) - Search for "select"

If you need to filter out the results too, you an use the [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)