# React Mongo select a specific field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I'm creating a react app and I connected my backend mongo where I want to store all my car brands, year, models etc. In react I'm using the select tag and there I get everything that is in the db. [DB running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86hbV.png). However, whenever I press a specific car brand and try to pick the year with another select tag it shows me the years of all the other car brands. How can I do it so it only shows me years of that specific car brand? [Should only show 2012](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbUp2.png).

My get function

```
carRoutes.route('/').get(function(req, res) {
    Car.find(function(err, car) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else{
            res.json(car);
        }
    }).collation().sort({car_description:1});
});
```

My Schema

```
let Car = new Schema({
    car_description: {
        type: String
    },
    car_year:{
        type: String
    }
});
```

Comment: `Car.find()` will send back _everything_. You need to pass a query object `Car.find({ car_year : 2012 })`

Comment: But this will only show me car brands from 2012. I only want it to filter whenever I select the specific car brand through the select tag. So for example if in my database I have Audi(2014), BMW(2012), Aud(2018), Mercedes(2020), and I press Audi in my select tagI will only get the years 2014, 2018

Comment: Can you please link to sample data so we can understand this more clearly

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose, Select a specific field with find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find)

Comment: Select your Audis with a distinct year : `find({car_description: 'Audi'}).distinct('car_year');` You'll get a list of years for Audi.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this (assuming car_description means the name):

```
Car.find({car_description: 'Audi'}).select('car_year -_id'); 
// you can replace 'Audi' with a variable which is assigned with the selected car name
```