# return all data in subarray inside subarray

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

this is my mongoose schema:

```
var book_listSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    userId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    first_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    last_name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    newList: [{
        list_name: String,
        books: [{
            list_name: String,
            book_name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            book_author: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            date_added: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            date_finished: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now
            },
            book_image: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }]
    }],
});

var book_list = mongoose.model('book_list', book_listSchema);

module.exports = book_list;
```

This is my query:

```
book_list.findOne({
        "userId": req.userContext.userinfo.sub
    }, {
        newList: {
            $elemMatch: {
                "list_name": listName
            }
        }
    })

    .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
    .limit(perPage)
    .exec(function(err, doc) {

        console.log(doc);

        response.render('display_list', {
            userContext,
            list_books: doc.newList[0].books,
            listName: listName,
            pages: Math.ceil(doc.newList[0].books.length / perPage),
            current: page
        })
    })
});
```

This is the doc/file that is returned:

```
{
    _id: new ObjectId("63b60f5844ffdd86146d6e5b"),
    newList: [{
        list_name: 'read',
        _id: new ObjectId("63b60f5844ffdd86146d6e5c"),
        books: [Array]
    }]
}
```

What I need returned is just the books:[Array]. I am trying to render the contents of the books:[Array] to a page with pagination.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mongoose, Select a specific field with find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24348437/mongoose-select-a-specific-field-with-find)

Comment: you need to add .select('books') before exec

Comment: @Shivam That does not answer my question because I am trying to retrieve an array inside an array, so I can't exclude the array newList because books[] is inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
book_list.findOne({
    "userId": req.userContext.userinfo.sub,
    "newList.list_name": listName
  }, {
    "newList.$.books": 1
  })
  .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
  .limit(perPage)
  .exec(function(err, doc) {
    console.log(doc);
    response.render('display_list', {
      userContext,
      list_books: doc.newList[0].books,
      listName: listName,
      pages: Math.ceil(doc.newList[0].books.length / perPage),
      current: page
    })
  })
});
```

It'll only return the array of books and if you use `doc.newList[0].books`, it will give you the array you want.

Make sure, `$` is a positional operator only project the 1st element that match the query, so if you have multiple lists with the same name, it'll just return the first one.

If you face any query. Please let me know

Comment: I received the error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'newList' of undefined

Comment: doc.newList[0].books is undefined error